# How to adding field's config on the fly?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to adding allow Blanks 's config when i click on a node in my Tree Panel !
if node is a leaf , i want to put name field's config : allowBlank : false 
and if not a leaf , allowBlank : true  .
I don't find method to do this ?!

Thanks a lot :)

---

Thanks to your answer but my combobox is not a global variable :

```
var monPrepanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{

        frame : true,
        title : 'Editing Zone',
        //renderTo : 'mesfields',
        //width : 750,
        forceFit : true,

        items: [{

                xtype:'fieldset',
                title: 'Add Task : ',
                margin : '20 20 20 20',

                collapsible: true,
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                layout: 'anchor',
                items: [ {

                itemId : 'p0',
                allowBlank : false,


         xtype : 'textfield',
    anchor : '60%',

         padding : '0 30 0 30',
          fieldLabel : 'Task',

          name : 'task'
        } , {

                itemId : 'p1',
                allowBlank : false,


         xtype : 'combobox',
            anchor : '40%',
            store : materialstore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'data',
            width : 50,
            valueField: 'data',
            editable : false,

         padding : '0 30 0 30',
          fieldLabel : 'Material',

          name : 'material'
        } , {

                allowBlank : true,

         xtype : 'combobox',
            anchor : '40%',
            store : ccstore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'data',
            width : 50,
            valueField: 'data',
            editable : false,

         padding : '0 30 0 30',
          fieldLabel : 'CC',

          name : 'cc'
        }
```

I need to access to the combobox component by id maybe ?
There are solutions to acess to this component into items to items ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set an `id` property for the desired combo box (`id: 'anyId'`), and use `Ext.apply(Ext.getCmp('anyId'), {your config object});`

Comment: how to get existing config, could you please replace `{your config object}` with existing config

Answer (score 5):

In general, this is how you "apply" changes to an Ext component that you have already created.

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({some initial config});

Ext.apply(combo, {your config object});
```

How are you loading your Treenodes?  You will probably do better by adding those properties from the back end if that's where it comes from.

Comment: Thank to your answer but my combobox is not a global variable

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  If you know what your DOM id is, you can get a reference to it using Ext.getCmp('myDomID');

Comment: Does this "apply" technique also work for those configs which alter the layout of component. For example, an Ext.form.FieldSet collapsible property is set to true after it is rendered. In my case layout is not updated:  Ext.apply(fieldset,{collapsible:true, style: "background:red"});

Comment: This updates the configuration of the object.  However, you may need to call doLayout() on the contain for which the component resides.