# Add Flex value dynamically to controller in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am giving some items (containers), in "View",  a layout of `hbox`. Now I want to give `flex` value to each item through the "Controller". How can I do this?

I have gone through the docs but can't find any method like `setFlex`.

**EDIT** :

```
Ext.apply(Ext.getCmp('IdHere'), {flex: 1});
```

I have got the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109705/1577396).
But now the problem is that even I am changing the flex values dynamically, the view of the containers is not changing. It is remaining same.

*I am not assigning flex values initially in "View" as stated [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-flex)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess would be that need to rerun the layout process by calling `doLayout()` I am not quite sure but I think you have to call in on the parent element which holds the `hbox` layout.

Comment: I know this method. But I wasn't aware of how to use. I was using this method on the containers instead of parent container. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Please assist me to solve this problem :)  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15429321/1577396

Answer (score 1):

Get your parent container (on which you have applied layout hbox or vbox) then get items and finally change the flex and update the layout

```
var ct = me.up('#parentComponent');
 ct.items.get('itemId1').flex = 2;
 ct.items.get('itemId2').flex = 2;
 ct.updateLayout();
```